# problem trying to redirect a specific url using SSL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect all https urls to http (except one account/payment):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} account/payment$
RewriteRule (.*)  https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !account/payment$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Works fine, except when I am going to http://url/account/payment, it's redirect me to http://url/index.php

Thank you

Comment: I think `REQUEST_URI` needs a `/` to match: `/account/payment$`

Comment: No because I specify account/payment$ and not ^account/payment$ so it should be match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [*L* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) causes a reinjection of the already rewritten URL into the rewriting process:

> Remember, however, that if the `RewriteRule` generates an internal redirect (which frequently occurs when rewriting in a per-directory context), this will reinject the request and will cause processing to be repeated starting from the first `RewriteRule`.

To avoid that either of your first two rules are applied on such a reinjected URL, check the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) instead:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /account/payment[?\ ]
RewriteRule ^account/payment$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\ /account/payment[?\ ]
RewriteRule !^account/payment$  http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time a `RewriteRule` matches, Apaches does an internal redirect and re-evaluates all the rewrite rules against the new (re-written) path.

So when `RewriteRule . index.php` matches, REQUEST_URI is changed to `index.php` and all rewrite rules are evaluated again.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !account/payment$` evaluates to true against `index.php`, and the next rule is evaluated: `RewriteRule (.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}`, which redirects (externally) to index.php.